# Can you use System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.CngKey in an Azure App Service?

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, cng

I would like to use RSA-encryption, including key creation and management, in an Azure App Service written in C#. Is it possible to use `System.Security.Cryptography.Cng` for that purpose? I couldn't get it to work because `CngKey.Create` seems to require administrator privilege. Is there a better alternative for public key management on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameter `keyName` is null in `CngKey.Create`, an ephemeral key is created, which doesn't require administrator privilege. The key information can be stored in e.g. Azure Key Vault.